# How to print underlined string

Tags: java

I am trying to underlying to string or label value. I tried this code:

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Underlined Label");
    Font font = label.getFont();
    Map attributes = font.getAttributes();
    attributes.put(TextAttribute.UNDERLINE, TextAttribute.UNDERLINE_ON);
    label.setFont(font.deriveFont(attributes));
    System.out.println(label.getText());
```

The output is Underlined Label and it didnt underline the label.
And also I tried

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel("<HTML><U>YOUR TEXT HERE</U></HTML>");
    label.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    System.out.println(label.getText());
```

This is also does not work. Can you help me please?

Comment: You are trying to output to the console (stdout) underlined text?

Comment: @ KevinO Yes, I tam trying to do this

Comment: Short answer, you can't

Comment: AFAIK, there is no standard, portable way to accomplish this task. You can, perhaps, accomplish this in Linux using escape codes (see [some examples here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528928/how-to-do-underline-bold-italic-strikethrough-color-background-and-size-i)). There appears to be a Windows API you could leverage for the Windows console.

Comment: @Kevino Actually I am trying to label inside of textfields and it should be some text not all, underlying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your terminal supports Unicode you can apply the combining diacritical mark U+0332 COMBINING LOW LINE to every character in your string:

```
public class Underline {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (String s : args) {
            StringBuilder underlined = new StringBuilder();
            for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
                underlined.append(c).append('\u0332');
            }
            System.out.println(underlined);
        }
    }
}
```

On my Windows 10 laptop, `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 Underline underlined` produces:

`u̲n̲d̲e̲r̲l̲i̲n̲e̲d̲`

Note: I am using mintty 2.8.4 as my terminal emulator. If your terminal doesn't have good Unicode support, this won't work.